# Multiple YUI form validators on the same page

Tags: forms, validation, yui, formvalidation-plugin

I have two forms on the same page. And I want to validate both these form with some YUI modules. I was able to validate a form as per my requirement by using the module aui-form-validator as below.

```
YUI().use('aui-form-validator', function(Y) {
        new Y.FormValidator(
          {
                boundingBox: '#form1',
                rules:{
                    answer:{
                        required : true,
                        minLength: 5,
                        maxLength: 600
                    }
                },
                fieldStrings:
                {
                    answer:{
                        required: "Please add the answer",
                        minLength: "Please enter atleast 5 characters",
                        maxLength: "Please enter no more than 600 characters"
                    }
                }
         });

});
```

The above code is working fine, but when I try to add the same set of code for vaidating form2, its not working. Only the one which wrote first is working.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

It would be more usefull if you could also provide the example that does not work,not only the working one.

Also I would suggest adding the AUI tag as you are not using pure YUI here.

Which version are you using?

Anyway, I've just tried with the following snippet and it worked for me:

```
<script src="http://cdn.alloyui.com/3.0.1/aui/aui-min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.alloyui.com/3.0.1/aui-css/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>

<form id="form1">
<input name="answer" type="text" value=""> 
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>

<form id="form2">
<input name="answer2" type="text" value=""> 
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>

<script>
YUI().use('aui-form-validator', function(Y) {
        new Y.FormValidator(
          {
                boundingBox: '#form1',
                rules:{
                    answer:{
                        required : true,
                        minLength: 5,
                        maxLength: 600
                    }
                },
                fieldStrings:
                {
                    answer:{
                        required: "Please add the answer",
                        minLength: "Please enter atleast 5 characters",
                        maxLength: "Please enter no more than 600 characters"
                    }
                }
         });


           new Y.FormValidator(
          {
                boundingBox: '#form2',
                rules:{
                    answer2:{
                        required : true,
                        minLength: 5,
                        maxLength: 600
                    }
                },
                fieldStrings:
                {
                    answer2:{
                        required: "Please add the answer2",
                        minLength: "Please enter atleast 5 answer2",
                        maxLength: "Please enter no more than 600 answer2"
                    }
                }
         });

});
</script>
```

Wdyt?